# Why is my ListBox displaying "(Collection)" instead of whats in my dictionary? (C# WinForms)

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary, listbox

Im trying to make an application that takes an input (via textbox), makes a dictionary entry based on that which has the URL as the key and the HTMLCode of that website as a value and i'm trying to display JUST the Key to a listbox, however, i am having some trouble.

My dictionary is populating correctly with the Url and the html however, the listbox i'm trying to make the keys display in is only displaying "(Collection)". I have tried several solutions i have seen and it still only displays (Collection)

I have been trying for several days to find a solution with no success. Thanks for reading.

Code follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;

namespace HtmlChecker
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
        }

        static SortedDictionary<string, WebsiteInfo> dict =
                new SortedDictionary<string, WebsiteInfo>();

        BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("Key");
            table.Columns.Add("Value");

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, WebsiteInfo> pair in dict)
            {
                table.Rows.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
            }
            bSource.DataSource = dict;

            this.lstDisplay.DisplayMember = "Value";
            this.lstDisplay.ValueMember = "Key";
            this.lstDisplay.DataSource = bSource;
        }

        private void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            addWebsite(txtUrl.Text);
        }    

        private static void addWebsite(string websiteUrl)
        {
            try
            {
                dict.Add(websiteUrl, new WebsiteInfo { WebsiteUrl = websiteUrl, HtmlCode = getHtml(websiteUrl) });
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }
        }

        public static string getHtml(string websiteUrl)
        {
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                return client.DownloadString(websiteUrl);
        }

    }

    public class WebsiteInfo
    {
        public string WebsiteUrl;
        public string HtmlCode;

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string formated = string.Format("{0}\n---------------------------------- \n{1}", WebsiteUrl, HtmlCode);
            return formated;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating the `table` object? Is that the one you meant to assign to `bSource.DataSource`?

Comment: Maybe try `foreach(var item in dict.Keys)`? I'm a little rusty with Winforms, so I'm not sure what it's expecting in terms of data.

Comment: @KyleBaran Just tried that, fortunately it doesnt display (Collection) but it doesnt seem to display anything at all, its probably due to it being in form_load but im not sure where else to put it

Comment: @PeterDuniho I initially wanted to display the keys and the htmlcode in a table inside the listbox but since im not wanting to display the htmlcode anymore i must have forgotten to take it out

Comment: If it's no longer displaying anything, it's probably iterating the Keys collection while it has 0 members.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change next code:

```
bSource.DataSource = dict;

this.lstDisplay.DisplayMember = "Value";
this.lstDisplay.ValueMember = "Key";
this.lstDisplay.DataSource = bSource;
```

To:

```
bSource.DataSource = table; //assign created table as DataSource

this.lstDisplay.DisplayMember = "Key"; //Column's name which you want to show in the list
this.lstDisplay.ValueMember = "Value";
this.lstDisplay.DataSource = bSource;
```